# Rails - self joins with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rails-activerecord

I have self join model called section:

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :offer
    # Self joins:
    has_many :child_sections, class_name: "Section", foreign_key: "parent_section_id"
    belongs_to :parent_section, class_name: "Section", optional: true
end
```

with migration file:

```
class CreateSections < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :sections do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :offer, foreign_key: true

      t.references :parent_section, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Working with mySql was fine, but then I dropped the databases, changed them to postresql (so they are heroku friendly), and created new ones. After trying `rails db:migrate` there is an error saying:

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "parent_sections" does not exist
```

What might have happened? Is there any difference between self joins in mysql and postgresql?

Answer (score 5):

Your `t.references` call:

```
t.references :parent_section, foreign_key: true
```

will try to do two things with PostgreSQL:

1. Add an integer column called `parent_section_id`.
2. Add a [foreign key constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) inside the database to ensure referential integrity (i.e. ensure that the values in `parent_section_id` reference sections that exist).

Your problem is with **2**. For `t.references :parent_section`, the FK would look like:

```
parent_section_id integer references parent_sections(id)
```

because it uses the standard Rails naming conventions, that's where your `parent_sections` error comes from. You can specify the target table for the FK constraint just like you can supply the `:class_name` to `belongs_to`:

```
t.references :parent_section, :foreign_key => { :to_table => :sections }
```

This fix trigger your next problem: you can't create an FK to a table that doesn't exist and `sections` won't exist until your `create_table :sections` block is finished executing.

There are two common solutions to this problem:

1. Create the table with all the columns and then add the FK constraint. Something like this in your migrations:

   ```
   create_table :sections do |t|
     t.string :name
     t.references :offer, foreign_key: true
     t.references :parent_section
     t.timestamps
   end
   add_foreign_key :sections, :sections, :column => :parent_section_id
   ```
2. Create the table without the referencing column (`parent_section_id`) and then add the referencing column and the FK after. Something like this in your migrations:

   ```
   create_table :sections do |t|
     t.string :name
     t.references :offer, foreign_key: true
     t.timestamps
   end
   change_table :sections do |t|
     t.references :parent_section, :foreign_key => { :to_table => :sections }
   end
   ```

Comment: What a great answer! I will try this as soon as I get back home. What I want to add is that error disappeared after doing db:reset, but still I couldn't make migrations afterwards.

Comment: @Ancinek make sure to accept the answer if that worked for you - it is a good practice and a "good-to-do" on SO to accept the answer that solved your issue. By doing so you are both rewarding the user who provided you with the solution **and** letting the community know, that the problem is resolved.